# How to Transform/Flatten this excel sheet

Tags: json, excel, transform, flatten

I have an excel sheet formatted thus:

[image]

And I would like to somehow change/transform this sheet into a flat format with one data item set item per column, so...

```
Qn Number
Sylabus
Question
Answer1
Answer2
Answer3
Answer4
Dummy Answer1
Dummy Answer2
Dummy Answer3
Dummy Answer4
Correct Answer1
Correct Answer2
Correct Answer3
Correct Answer4
```

If I am honest, I have no idea how best to accomplish this as eventually I want the data in json format but in the meantime I would be happy to work with data in the format above.

Could someone advise how best to accomplish this please?

Answer (score 0):

You could execute an SQL statement, either from Python or VBA or some other language, like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Question AS Item
    FROM [Sheet1$]

    UNION ALL SELECT 'Answer' + Answer
    FROM [Sheet1$]

    UNION ALL SELECT Answers
    FROM [Sheet1$]
) AS t1
WHERE Item IS NOT NULL
```

(Although I'm not quite clear what you want to do with the `Correct Answer` column.)

Also, it's probably important to check that the results come back in order.

---

From VBA (and assuming an Excel host), you could use code like the following to execute the SQL statement, and paste the data into a new worksheet:

```vba
Const filepath As String = "C:\path\to\excel\file.xlsx"
Const sheetname As String = "Sheet1"

Dim connectionString As String
connectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""" & filepath & """;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"""

    ' If your data is in a macro-enabled file (.xlsm), the previous line should
    ' look like this:
    ' "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=No"""

Dim sql As String
sql = _
    "SELECT * " & _
    "FROM (" & _
        "SELECT Question AS Item " & _
        "FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
        "UNION ALL SELECT 'Answer' + Answer " & _
        "FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
        "UNION ALL SELECT Answers " & _
        "FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
    ") AS t1 " & _
    "WHERE Item IS NOT NULL"

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open sql, connectionString

Workbooks.Open(filepath).Worksheets.Add.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset(rs)
```

You can certainly do something similar in Python.

---

As far as JSON goes, VBA doesn't have native JSON support, but you could import the module from [VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON). Then you could produce JSON as follows:

```vba
Dim json As String
json = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(rs.GetRows)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Zev, alas no way for me to easily run SQL Queries.

Comment: @John I've updated my answer. (Methinks it verily quite simple, no need for an "alas" .)

Comment: Thanks Zev, haha, I meant I am not anywhere near an expert, and therefore it isn't easy for me :)

Comment: @John Not yet, at any rate . Seriously, the question is only how far out of your comfort zone does it make sense for you to go, and in which direction; and also more precisely, what is your current comfort zone? i.e. if you're familiar with Python, or C#, or Perl, it's possible to do something similar -- treat the Excel file as though it were a database table.